# Different users in PGAdmin Web and PGAdmin Desktop Application

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

When I was trying to access PGAdmin Web and PGAdmin Desktop (maybe called as Client), I found that Web version and Desktop version are showing different users. I want to have same user across both the versions. Though I used different accounts, I got access to same server.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, PGAdmin4 version: 6.18, PostgreSQL version:14.6

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Database roles are maintained on cluster level, not in a database nor client. Most likely you are connected to a different cluster

Comment: Do you have any fix for this?

Comment: Please add more info to your question, like the output of `\conninfo`, to start with, and the usernames you use to connect to the database. Also the users that are defined (`SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user;`) might be of interest to say anything usefull.

Comment: Check your database connections, they should be the same.

Comment: I use same username for both the versions(I remember creating both the accounts with same username).Sorry, my bad, can't give much information about that. The output of `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_user;` on both the versions is same. But Server names are different in them(I created them differently). The place where it gets really difficult is:I created accounts with same username and same passwords. But, due to different server names, I came to conclusion that they are different